# validate textarea with jquery and validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

i use this plug as my text editor [elrte](http://elrte.org/)

when i tried to validate the text area within the jquery validation plugin it didn't work

```
var ArticleFormValidation = {};
                ArticleFormValidation.init =
                {
                    setArticleFormValidation: function()
                    {
                        //form validation rules
                        $("#ArticleForm").validate({
                            rules: {
                                ArticleTitle: "required",
                                slug: "required",
                                editor: "required"

                            },
                            messages: {
                                ArticleTitle: "Please enter article title",
                                slug: "Please enter article slug",
                                editor: "Please enter article body"
                            }


                        }); 
                    }
                }
```

it used to validate the first 2 fields only ArticleTitle,Slug and didn't validate the text area and when i removed the text editor code and get the field back as normal text area it works

and this is the code for calling the text area

```
 var opts = {
                cssClass : 'el-rte',
                // lang     : 'ru',
                height   : 450,
                toolbar  : 'complete',
                cssfiles : ['../libs/elrte/css/elrte-inner.css']
            }
    $('#editor').elrte(opts);
```

what i need to do is to validate the text area when it becomes an editor because its useless to use it as normal text area

Answer (score 0):

Can you validate it separately?

```
if($('textareaid').val().Trim().Length == 0 ){

// alert

}
```

Alternatively as a hackaround you could have a hidden input as a text area and mimic the typing of the main text area into this field and validate this. The hidden input could be a textbox or text area. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AuBn8/)

Comment: i know i can do this through seperated function but i would like to use the form validation plugin since i use to validate the whole form

Comment: OK How about the fiddle option? Just add the hidden element id to the validation plug in and it should work being it is a standard textbox?